# Remake xib to storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm adding subviews to the UIScrollView and I'm using xib files. I want to rewrite it all, but using storyboards. How can I do rewrite this piece of code?

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < [glyphs count]; i++)
    {
        GlyphView *aView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GlyphView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        aView.glyphLabel.text = [glyphs objectAtIndex:i];
        aView.frame = CGRectMake(glyphScrollView.frame.size.width * i, 0, glyphScrollView.frame.size.width, glyphScrollView.frame.size.height);
        [glyphScrollView addSubview:aView];
    }
```

Comment: CMD-C and CMD-V,copy like files.

Comment: And remake your outlets and target-actions.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to rewrite this code to storyboards

Comment: I see.Just use a table view to contain these views.Storyboard isn't good at this.

Answer (score 0):

I've a tip on how to add independent `UIView` in storyboard here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1069081/Independent-UIView-in-storyboard.

You can add `UIView` by following above tutorial in storyboard, map `UIView` class to your `GlyphView`. 
Have a IBoutlet of this view in your controller.
Now your code which you written above will be changed to shown below.

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < [glyphs count]; i++)
{
    GlyphView *aView = self.glymphView;
    aView.glyphLabel.text = [glyphs objectAtIndex:i];
    aView.frame = CGRectMake(glyphScrollView.frame.size.width * i, 0, glyphScrollView.frame.size.width, glyphScrollView.frame.size.height);
    [glyphScrollView addSubview:aView];
}
```